# Background of the control is becoming dark on minimising and maximizing the window

Tags: visual-c++, mfc, cedit

Control background is getting changed after minimizing and maximizing the window.
I want the background to be same and transparent.

[image: Before minimizing the window]

[image: After maximizing the window]

This is an ActiveX control. which can be used in multiple projects.
CEdit is the base class for this control on which I have added some extra feature.
I tried setting Bkmode in OnCtlColor and OnCtlColor but it is not working out.

Comment: Could you provide more details ? What kind of control it is there ? Doesn't look as standard.

Comment: And, please provide any appropriate code that might help illustrate your problem.

Comment: I have edited the question. please let me know if you need more information.

Comment: A [mcve] is required. Make sure to make it minimal.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this by fetching the background color and filling the rec of the control

```
BOOL CComboBoxCtrl::OnEraseBkgnd(CDC* pDC) 
{
COleControl::OnEraseBkgnd(pDC);
RECT rc,rc1;
GetClientRect(&rc);
// Get the color from the parent window
COLORREF crBkgnd = COleControl::AmbientBackColor();

//Fill the rect to overcome the black background issue
pDC->FillSolidRect(&rc,crBkgnd);

if(inputbox != NULL)
    inputbox->Invalidate(TRUE);
return S_OK;
```

}

Comment: `S_OK` is a COM `HRESULT` (that evaluates to 0). Since you did erase the background, [OnEraseBkgnd](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a0a52fkz.aspx) should return a non-zero value. Besides, you aren't using `rc1`. Why is it there? And why do you ignore compiler warnings?